Simple exception in Visual Studio that I can't solve about an "InvalidOperationException"
I was following a tutorial from Brackeys on C#, I am trash at programming, and I am also starting out.
Nonetheless, I got this error (see attached screenshot) after writing the line:
Console.ReadKey();

This is not my only line, you also have like the basic starting stuff, like
static void Main(string[] args)

so that is not the problem.
This is the error:

I also have to include the error directly in the post, so:

Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Console.dll: 'Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.'
at System.ConsolePal.ReadKey(Boolean intercept)
at Code_and_stuff.Program.Main(String[] args) in
C:\Users\Anonymous\OneDrive - Random School\Bureaublad\Code and
stuff\Program.cs:line 10

I only really tried to remove the brackets in Console.ReadKey();, but that didn't work, I could have installed the wrong .NET framework, but so far everything has worked fine, I have already ran my program beforehand, and the only thing change that i made before the error was changing my console, I changed it to externalTerminal, however, I later changed it to internalConsole (it's standard state) and I still got the error.
And so I can't run my program now.
If you want the complete code:
using System;

namespace Code_and_stuff 
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I Love Water!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}


Are you running this in a command line?  Remember if you do xxx.exe < infile.txt, for example, then you don't have a connection to the input terminal at all.

@TimRoberts I don't think so, i am new, but i assume not, is it fair to compare the command line to the terminal? Because then, no.

It would be a good idea to post your code

@Mayfair it is very simple code... like i said, i just started, it wouldn't be of use i think.
I will edit my original question

Perhaps you should tell us exactly how you are running it.  What you have written there is a console app, meaning it is intended to be run in a terminal window.  If you're trying to create a GUI app, then you don't use the Console APIs.

@TimRoberts But i want to run it into a terminal window, i suppose that the change from InternalConsole to ExternalTerminal only made the output that would have appeared in the terminal kind of get a windowed form. But i think Rahul Sharma has the answer, still gotta check.

@RahulSharma I already tried what was done in the verified answer, and one other answer. I have also used Console.In.
So, no.

I don't know if this is a practical solution but uhm, it works when i run without debugging, is this sufficient enough to be declared as a correct answer? Or, no? If i can't verify my own answer as correct, you can copy or at least paraphrase my answer, i will verify it as correct.
If it is really not a practical solution, i suggest we keep this question open.
